# Urlfetch blobs multipart/m

Tags: http-headers, google-apps-script

I am trying to use UlrFetch to submit CSV data to Zoho reports. I am using the following code:

```
function doImport(tabla,file) {
  var url="https://reportsapi.zoho.com/api/xxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyyyyy/"+tabla;
  var ticket="zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz" ;//getTicket();
  url=url + "?ZOHO_ACTION=IMPORT&ZOHO_OUTPUT_FORMAT=XML&ZOHO_ERROR_FORMAT=json&ZOHO_API_VERSION=1.0"
  var params={"ZOHO_API_KEY":"vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv"
              ,"ticket":ticket
              ,"ZOHO_FILE":file
              ,"ZOHO_IMPORT_TYPE":"APPEND"
              ,"ZOHO_ON_IMPORT_ERROR":"ABORT"
              ,"ZOHO_AUTO_IDENTIFY":"true"
              ,"ZOHO_CREATE_TABLE":"false"
              ,"ZOHO_DATE_FORMAT":"dd-MM-YYYY"
              ,"ZOHO_DELIMITER":"0"
             };

  var options =
    {
      "method" : "post",
      "payload" : params,
      "contentType": "multipart/form-data"
    };
  var response=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var tableDataString=response.getContentText();
  expireTicket(ticket);
  Logger.log(tableDataString);
  return tableDataString;
}
```

However, the data is not submitted in correct multiform format (getting error 500 status). This issue backtracks to [early 2011](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/apps-script/urlfetch%2420multipart/apps-script/qpJCDYtaSDQ/e4gqaaaq-AMJ). Please, one or two examples of how to submit blob files in multipart/form-data format would be welcome.

Thanks

Comment: UrlFetch can now accept a byte[] as the payload value to the argument Object.  Blob.getBytes() works sufficiently for that.

In terms of a multipart request, as I understand it, that isn't binary.  So I don't think you can mix the two (in any platform) as you're suggesting.  What's the URL for the API you're trying to interface with and how?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using the API described at http://zohoreportsapi.wiki.zoho.com/Importing-CSV-File.html and it works from other platforms. Do you have an example of multipart form data submission?

Answer (score 2):

For payload, you are passing it as an `Object`, which looks correct. This will be interpreted as an HTTP form (which you want).

To fix your script, try the following:

1. Make sure the value you're using for `ZOHO_FILE` is a Blob. This makes sure the HTTP form will automatically be sent with:
   `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=[automatically determined]`
2. Do not specify `contentType` for the HTTP POST. This allows UrlFetchApp to automatically use its own `contentType` value, which includes the `boundary` field.  (Minor detail: It's ok to still specify contentType on the Blob itself, just not the overall post request. This allows specifying the contentType of each Blob within the post, if that interests you.)

Answer (score 1):

UrlFetchApp will use multipart/form-data encoding automatically if you pass a Blob as a payload value. You may need to use:

```
"ZOHO_FILE": file.getBlob()
```